# html/css - html website with multiple pages - have one menu that can be called?

Tags: html, css, menu, call

MY SERVER IS TOO BASIC TO SUPPORT PHP/JAVASCRIPT, ANY SUGGESTIONS?

I have a HTML website with multiple pages. I am using an identical menu on all pages and when I add a page I have to each page and edit the code.

I am wondering is there a way of adding a menu page that can be called?

I am using CSS/HTML is it possible to do anything to help? I have researched a bit and I think it involves PHP, but can PHP be used in conjuncion with CSS/HTML?

Comment: For instance I currently have 2 pages - eg. MySite.html and my MySite.css. what do I need to do to these and what pages do i need to add.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the code for your menu in a separate html and call it in all your other html files

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test page</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    Rest of the Header Content
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="content">
    Main Content
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="footer">
    Footer Content
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#menu").load("menu.html");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, I will try to adapt this to get it working within my application

Comment: if you were able to get this working, kindly do accept this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use php to be able to do that.

Do 2 separate files, one will be your `index.php` and the other `menu.php`

To include `menu.php` you have to add :

```
<?php include '../elements/menu.php'; ?>
```

in your `index.php`.

All your other elements still can be coded in HTML even if your new extension is .php

You include this menu on all your website pages and if you want to add a page, you just have to add the link in `menu.php` and it will appear everywhere.

Comment: so does this now mean I will have have a html page, a css page and 2 PHP pages?

Comment: I have now done this but it does not appear to work for me?

Comment: Are you running it on a server ?

Comment: Yes, i'd even make 3 PHP pages + 1 CSS

Comment: If you are working on a server side script like PHP; I would highly recommend this method over the answer posted by me using plain JavaScript. In most scenarios JS doesn't render well in all browsers and devices (esp mobiles) and in some cases the JS might be disabled on browsers for security reasons. In such cases, you might end up getting an JS error at the bottom of the main page and no menu.

Comment: my server cannot support PHP

Comment: I dont know what kind of server you are running, but if you are admin, you could install apache on it. There is a lot of documentation on the web. If you only want to try it locally you can install LAMP ( or WAMP for Windows ) and PHP will work. If you have a webserver, contact your host to ask him why PHP isn't running because it should. Hope i helped :)

Answer (score 1):

just use @Html.Render("pagename.html");

Comment: I cannot seem to get any of your answers to work out, is there any onlline resource where i could see a working prototype?

Comment: search for 'master layout in html'